# How to load data from query into table on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have The following `BigQuery` tables:

`orders`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "orders_id",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "customer_id",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
]
```

`customers`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "customer_id",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "customer_name",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
]
```

I want to create `new_orders` as follows:

```
[
    {
        "name": "orders_id",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "customer_name",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
]
```

So I created an empty table for `new_orders` and wrote this query:

```
SELECT o.orders_id,c.customer_name
from `project.orderswh.orders` as o
inner join `project.orderswh.customers` as c  on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

My problem is how to load the data from this query result into the new table.
I have like 15M rows. To the best of my knowledge regular insert is cost-expensive and incredibly slow. How can I do this as a load job?

Comment: do you want to run it via API with Python ?

Comment: @rtbf if this could be done with the UI the better as this is one time thing. If not then BigQuery cli tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this from [BigQuery Console](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/)

There follow these steps:

```
1) Show Options 

2) Destination Table 

3) choose dataset and provide "new_orders" as Table ID 

4) then set "Write Preference" to "Write if empty" as this is one time thing as you said
```

If needed, look also for this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [bq](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool) command line tool:

```
    bq query --append_table \
             --nouse_legacy_sql \
             --allow_large_results \
             --destination_table project.orderswh.new_orders 'SELECT o.orders_id,c.customer_name
from `project.orderswh.orders` as o
inner join `project.orderswh.customers` as c  on o.customer_id = c.customer_id'
```